# "Combine" 2 variables to declare a new one?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am new to coding and I am trying to declare a variable that refers to 2 "combined" previously declared variables as followed :

```
var player1 = "Red", player2 = "Blue", player3 = "Green";
var p=1;
var Red = {x: 2, y: 4};
var Blue = {x: 6, y: 2};
var Green = {x: 8, y: 1};

var x = player+p.x; // should be player+1 so "Red" so x=2 
var y = player+p.y; // should be y=4

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

x and y should be the coordinates of player n°p depending on the color of that player (in this example player n°1).

I hope it's clear enough ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: `var x = player+p.x;`: `p.x` doesn't work because `p` is a numerical value, not an object. Also, you do not have any variable named `player`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think OP's trying to access variables dynamically : `player+p` would be `player1` and `player1`'s value is "Red". Get `x` from `Red` object. Array or an object with each player as key is a better option

Comment: @adiga Yah, I can see that. So probably means something more like `var x = "player" + p`. And then trying to use that as a variable name.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do.. But then that variable x equals a string "player1" and not the variable player1 .. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for what I think you want:

```
var players = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"];
var p = 1;
console.log(players[p]);
```

If you need more info for each player, then this can be an array of objects:

```
var players = [{color: 'Red', x: 2, y: 3}, // etc]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be searching for an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Object):

```js
var players = [
  {
    name: "Red",
    x: 2,
    y: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Blue",
    x: 6,
    y: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Green",
    x: 8,
    y: 1
  }
];

players.forEach((player,index)=>{
  console.log(`Player ${index+1} = ${player.name} position is = x:${player.x},y:${player.y}`);
});
```

This way, you can access the element you want by doing: `players[index]`. And to get its properties, you just need to call it like this: `players[index].name` for the name.